G*Power Mixed two-way ANOVA power analysis - sample size seems too small?
I am running my first-ever power analysis and I am worried that I am misunderstanding something about G*Power. I am running a 2x2 mixed ANOVA. I chose the 'ANOVA: Repeated measures, within-between interaction" option and I left Cohen's d at the default 0.25 just to get an idea. When I adjusted the power to .80, the total sample size was calculated to be only 34 - I am a little shocked that it suggests only 17 people in each group would be sufficient. I used to do animal research and that's about a sample size I'd use with my rats. Does this sound right to you, or is there something about the software that I'm not understanding? Thank you!
Parameters:
Effect size f: 0.25
alpha err prob: .05
Power: .80
Number of groups: 2
Number of measurements: 2
Corr among rep measures: 0.5
Nonsphericity correction epsilon: 1

@dipetkov provided an excellent link, with one of the answers explaining this. Generally, repeated measure designs have high power for reasonable N because each subject serves as their own control.  In your input, the only thing that might be off is the correlation between repeated measures. . 0.5 might be a good choice, or it might not, depending on what you are measuring and how precisely and reliably you are measuring it.
